# Ansible using python3 virtualenv not working with python3 site-packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible

How to replicate the problem:

1. Install Ansible "outside" virtual environment `/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install ansible`
2. Install python3 virtual environment `python3 -m venv /usr/local/kaas_virtualenv`
3. Install a python module into virtual environment `/usr/local/kaas_virtualenv/bin/python3 -m pip install jmespath`

Ansible playbook and inventory:

**playbook.yaml**

```
---
- hosts: control_host
  gather_facts: yes
  become: no
  environment:
    PYTHONPATH: "/usr/local/kaas_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages"

  vars:
    my_users:
      - password: 123
        username: broker
      - password: 321
        username: broker2
      - password: 213
        username: broker3

  tasks:
    - name: print users
      debug:
        msg: "users = {{ my_users|json_query('[*].username') }}"
```

**server_inventory**

```
[control_host]
localhost

[control_host:vars]
ansible_connection=local
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/kaas_virtualenv/bin/python3
```

Run playbook: `ansible-playbook -i server_inventory playbook.yaml`

**Expected output:**

```
PLAY [control_host] ***********************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [print users] ***********************
ok: [localhost] => {}

MSG:

users = ['broker', 'broker2', 'broker3']

PLAY RECAP ***********************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

**Actual output:**

```
bash-4.2# ansible-playbook -i server_inventory playbook.yaml -vvvv
ansible-playbook 2.9.6
  config file = /ansible-dev/swap/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/ansible-dev/swap/library']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.7.6 (default, Feb 26 2020, 20:54:15) [GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6)]
Using /ansible-dev/swap/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /ansible-dev/swap/server_inventory as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /ansible-dev/swap/server_inventory as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /ansible-dev/swap/server_inventory as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Set default localhost to localhost
Parsed /ansible-dev/swap/server_inventory inventory source with ini plugin
Loading callback plugin debug of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/debug.py

PLAYBOOK: playbook.yaml ***********************
Positional arguments: playbook.yaml
verbosity: 4
connection: smart
timeout: 10
become_method: sudo
tags: ('all',)
inventory: ('/ansible-dev/swap/server_inventory',)
forks: 5
1 plays in playbook.yaml

PLAY [control_host] ***********************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************
task path: /ansible-dev/swap/playbook.yaml:2
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~root && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1587713210.496898-92940637298090 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1587713210.496898-92940637298090="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1587713210.496898-92940637298090 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/system/setup.py
<localhost> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-3398m567tl8a/tmprytb4g6g TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1587713210.496898-92940637298090/AnsiballZ_setup.py
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1587713210.496898-92940637298090/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1587713210.496898-92940637298090/AnsiballZ_setup.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/kaas_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages /usr/local/kaas_virtualenv/bin/python3 /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1587713210.496898-92940637298090/AnsiballZ_setup.py && sleep 0'
ok: [localhost]
META: ran handlers

TASK [print users] ***********************
task path: /ansible-dev/swap/playbook.yaml:18
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {}

MSG:

You need to install "jmespath" prior to running json_query filter

PLAY RECAP **********************
```

**Ansible installation:**

```
bash-4.2# ansible --version
ansible 2.9.6
  config file = /ansible-dev/swap/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/ansible-dev/swap/library']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.7.6 (default, Feb 26 2020, 20:54:15) [GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6)]
```

The problem occurs even if I activate virtualenv `. /usr/local/kaas_virtualenv/bin/activate` and run ansible-playbook `ansible-playbook -i server_inventory playbook.yaml -vvvv`

Running the playbook with **virtualenv activated:**

```
(kaas_virtualenv) bash-4.2# ansible-playbook -i server_inventory playbook.yaml -vvvv
ansible-playbook 2.9.6
  config file = /ansible-dev/swap/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/ansible-dev/swap/library']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.7.6 (default, Feb 26 2020, 20:54:15) [GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6)]
Using /ansible-dev/swap/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /ansible-dev/swap/server_inventory as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /ansible-dev/swap/server_inventory as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /ansible-dev/swap/server_inventory as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Set default localhost to localhost
Parsed /ansible-dev/swap/server_inventory inventory source with ini plugin
Loading callback plugin debug of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/debug.py

PLAYBOOK: playbook.yaml ***********************
Positional arguments: playbook.yaml
verbosity: 4
connection: smart
timeout: 10
become_method: sudo
tags: ('all',)
inventory: ('/ansible-dev/swap/server_inventory',)
forks: 5
1 plays in playbook.yaml

PLAY [control_host] ***********************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************
task path: /ansible-dev/swap/playbook.yaml:2
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~root && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1587716569.74761-59629609450822 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1587716569.74761-59629609450822="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1587716569.74761-59629609450822 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/system/setup.py
<localhost> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-4319jytc92b2/tmpwbji1240 TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1587716569.74761-59629609450822/AnsiballZ_setup.py
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1587716569.74761-59629609450822/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1587716569.74761-59629609450822/AnsiballZ_setup.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/kaas_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages /usr/local/kaas_virtualenv/bin/python3 /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1587716569.74761-59629609450822/AnsiballZ_setup.py && sleep 0'
ok: [localhost]
META: ran handlers

TASK [print users] ***********************
task path: /ansible-dev/swap/playbook.yaml:18
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {}

MSG:

You need to install "jmespath" prior to running json_query filter

PLAY RECAP ***********************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Checking pythom module with virtualenv **activated**:

```
(kaas_virtualenv) bash-4.2# python -c "import jmespath"
(kaas_virtualenv) bash-4.2#
```

Checking pythom module with virtualenv **deactivated**:

```
bash-4.2# python -c "import jmespath"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named jmespath
bash-4.2#
```

The only place where python module exist:

```
bash-4.2# find / -name jmespath
/usr/local/kaas_virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jmespath
bash-4.2#
```

Comment: Have you activated your virtual env that you installed to `/usr/local/kaas_virtualenv`? If yes, could you run `python -c "import jmespath"`? My assumption is that you are running Ansible outside of the virtual env.

Comment: @vkozyrev - yes we are running Ansible outside virtual env.
If I activate the virtual env `. /usr/local/kaas_virtualenv/bin/activate` and run above command `(kaas_virtualenv) bash-4.2# python -c "import jmespath"` I don't get any thing back.

Comment: Well, then there is no point of installing jmespath into virtual env if you do not activate it. This is the reason why your setup does not work.

Comment: @vkozyrev even when activated, output above, it fail "Running the playbook with **virtualenv activated:**".

Answer (score 1):

Ansible filter plugins **are** not using `ansible_python_interpreter`. Filter plugins must follow Ansible installation and have their dependencies where Ansible are installed.

Filters ALWAYS run on the controller, since templating ONLY happens on the controller, otherwise it would require jinja2 + passing all inventory +all variables to the remote, which we don't do for many reasons.

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/69148